# Plot two curves and their confidence interval

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have two similar data.frame's and i can plot each one of them on `ggplot2` with its confidence interval. my question is how i can plot both of them on the same graph?
Here is the script which allows me to plot the first dataframe, the second is basically similar to this one, same scales and close values.

```
xlabel <- "Frequency [Hz]"
ylabel <- "|Z|[Ohm]"
plotdata <- data.frame(x=x6, y=mediaprobes, lower = (mediaprobes_m), upper = (mediaprobes_M))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plotdata) + geom_line(aes(y= y, x= x6, colour = "Mean probes"))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper, x=x6, fill = "st.err"), alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_colour_manual("",values="blue")+
  scale_fill_manual("",values="grey12")+ 
  xlab(xlabel) + 
  ylab(ylabel)+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))
```

second dataframe

```
plotdatas <- data.frame(x=x6, y=mediaprobes, lower = (mediaprobes_m), upper = (mediaprobes_M))
```

this is how the dataframes looks like:

```
      x           y      lower    upper
      1000000.0  2175.0  2127.042  2222.958
      932600.0   2290.0  2239.668  2340.332


 x           y2         lower2     upper2
 1000000.0  2454.593   2435.686  2473.500
 932600.0   2580.815   2561.698   2599.932
```

Comment: If you share some dummy data perhaps we could be of more help. In short, you need to join the data.frames and add another column which tells you from which DF the data came from. This will be used to color/stylize/facet your data according to DF (source).

Answer (score 1):

Add group status to each table and then bind them using `rbind`. In ggplot specify color/fill by the group ("A" or "B") you have added.

```
# We have to change column names to match plotdata
colnames(plotdatas) <- c("x", "y", "lower", "upper")
plotdata$group <- "A"
plotdatas$group <- "B"
pd <- rbind(plotdata, plotdatas)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pd, aes(x, y, fill = group)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), 
                alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "black")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey40", "grey1"))
```

Result:

[image]